# Make monitor higher on desk

Tags: substitute-tool, technology, hardware

I used to have textbooks beneath my computer monitor, but I sold them to get some money back. Now my monitor's several inches too low. Instead of paying [$40 for a new stand](http://www.amazon.ca/3M-Adjustable-Monitor-Stand-MS80B/dp/B0006HVM5E/ref=sr_1_8/188-8453741-0119922?s=pc&ie=UTF8&qid=1452387141&sr=1-8), is there a way I can make my own? I was thinking a phone book would work well but I don't have one. I have old shoe boxes but I don't think they're strong enough.

Comment: How does this require a life hack? You just need something thick and solid. Either get some pieces of board, or possibly buy some second hand books. Regarding phone books you should easily be able to get them at some second hand book store or similar.

Comment: @holroy that is the question, what is the most cost effective? Books, especially big ones, are expensive and can cost hundreds of dollars. What do you mean pieces of board, like wood planks?

Comment: That is why I suggest second hand books. You should be able to get some either for free, or just for a few dollar.

Answer (score 2):

Concrete cinder blocks or bricks can be used to raise your monitor. They have the advantages of being cheap, easily available, and heavy enough to stay in place.

*The blocks pictured below have a textured side which you may not want.*

[image: Different types of concrete cinder blocks]

Image from diy.com

Comment: The flat one looks quite useful 

Answer (score 1):

Newspaper will work.  It has the added bonus if being easy to work with as well as controlling the resulting height.

Answer (score 1):

You said you had books, maybe you can get some inexpensive books to put back there. Old phonebooks of previous years may do the trick - they are tick and after a couple years nobody wants them anymore (as they are outdated and there are newer versions anyway).

Answer (score 1):

Use ream(s) of printer paper.  Stable, scalable, you already have them lying around your computer area.